# Trying to convert python to terminal command

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, python

Trying to create a mouse mover that I can call anywhere using command prompt so my computer doesn't shut off.

I've included the following at the top of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

# use 0o (zero + "o" before 755 to use octal)   
os.chmod('/path/to/file.py', 0o755)
```

but when i call ./file.py, it returns the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’: No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to solve this been at it for while.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal do you get any output from

```
which python3
```

If not, the you'll have you to install it.

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Alternatively if you were developing the code in a virtual environment, you'd want to activate it first, before running your program on the command line.